# ClassCastException when casting from Object[] to Comparable[]

Tags: java, casting

Edit: Noticed the post was flagged as duplicate; I read through the other, similar, question but it really didn't treat the same problem as mine. I'm working with a class that is guaranteed to be of the type Comparable, yet I can't cast it.

I have the following class, which is an implementation of an interface Queue. I make sure that the type which HeapPriorityQueue object works with implements Comparable, so that the method E.compareTo(E other) is available.

I create an instance of HeapPriorityQueue in my main method. Where Patient is a class that implements Comparable

```
HeapPriorityQueue<Patient> queue = new HeapPriorityQueue<>();
```

At compilation however, I get an exception ClassCastException which points towards the last line in the code below

```
public class HeapPriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Queue<E>
{

    private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

    private int size;
    private E[] array;

    public HeapPriorityQueue()
    {
        size = 0;
        array = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1];
    }
}
```

> The exception:
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;

Comment: Is there some reason (e.g. teacher said so) that it needs to be an array specifically? There are other data structures (e.g. `List<E>`) that might better suit you...

Comment: @dcsohl I am limited in my choices. It's a course about data structures, so I imagine my choices are either singly linked lists or arrays for the heap structure.

Comment: I would definitely go for some sort of `List` here, even if you have to write it yourself. As you have found, you cannot do `new E[size];` and you cannot cast from an `Object[]` to an `E[]` (which you would not want to do, even if you could, since your new `Object[]` is full of `Object`s and not `E`s!). Your best bet is probably `ArrayList`. Whether or not that's allowed is a different question. Although I do have to ask... if it's a **Heap**PriorityQueue, shouldn't you be setting up a Heap and not an Array/List?

Comment: @dcsohl I'm under the impression that a heap can be built up from an array. That you could place a bunch of elements in an array and say that k:th's left child node is 2*k, and k:th's right child node is 2*k + 1. Is this not how it works?

Comment: Huh. Ok, yeah, sure, I suppose you could do that, if you felt like being masochistic (or had a sadistic teacher making you do that). I'd personally create a quick little `Node<E>` class that had a value and right and left children. I think the data structure manipulations would be easier that way. But this is veering off-topic for this question...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working with a class that is guaranteed to be of the type Comparable, yet I can't cast it.

`new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1];` doesn't guarantee anything instead of the fact that it's an object array. An object array can't be safely cast to a Comparable array.

You'd have to use something like:

```
Class<E> clazz;
array = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
```